# How rare are 1024-bit $B$-smooth numbers?

Tags: rsa, padding

What is the probability that if I choose a random $1 < r < n - 1$, $r^{65537} \pmod n$ will be $B$-smooth?  $n$ is a 1024-bit RSA modulus.

The Wikipedia pages on [smooth numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number#Distribution) and the [Dickman function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickman_function) are too obtuse for me to understand enough to calculate for my particular case.

I was contemplating an attack on something that uses a broken PKCS #1 v1.5 signature padding check.  I figured that if I found find many such $r$, I could forge signatures by manipulating the unchecked parts of the "message representative" to make it factor over the factor base $B$.  The signature then would be calculable as a linear matrix.

This all resembles parts of the quadratic sieve algorithm.  Quadratic sieve would be too difficult to do on a 1024-bit number, so it's quite possible that this attack idea is infeasible just from the rarity of smooth numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $n$ is a 1024-bit RSA modulus usable with $e=65537$ (as in the attack contemplated, and for >99.99% of $n=p\;q$ with $p$ and $q$ prime), then $r\mapsto r^{65537}\bmod n$ is a permutation of the set $[2,n-2]$. Thus if $r$ is uniformly random in this set, then so is $r^{65537}\bmod n$. For cryptanalytic purposes, it suffices that $r$ is chosen independently of the particular $n$.

The proportion of $B$-smooth among these is $\psi(n,B)/n$, and for fixed ratio $u=\log(n)/\log(B)$ and large $n$ that's $\rho(u)+O(1/\log(n))$, where $\rho$ is [Dickman's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickman_function) [in its modern definition; Donald E. Knuth's [*The Art of Computer Programming*](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/taocp.html), section 4.5.4, studies $F(x)=\rho(1/x)$ ]. In cryptanalysis, $\rho(\log(n)/\log(B))$ is often used as an approximation of the density of $B$ smooth, ignoring the $O(1/\log(n))$ term. **Caution**: I can't tell how justified that is!

For example, if $B=2^{256}$, the proportion of $B$-smooth among integers less than $2^{1024}$ is approximately $\rho(1024/256)=\rho(4)\approx 0.00491\approx2^{-7.67}$. For $B=2^{128}$ that approximation is down to $\rho(8)\approx2^{-24.88}$.

Here is a table of $\log_2(\rho(u))$ for $u$ from $1$ to $25$ by steps of $\frac1 4$ (obtained using [that code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59431/5289)).
$$\begin{array}{r|rrrrrrrrr}
u&+0&+\frac1 4&+\frac1 2&+\frac3 4&+1\\
\hline
1&0\ \ \ \ \ &-0.36&-0.75&-1.18&-1.70\\
2&-1.70&-2.30&-2.94&-3.62&-4.36\\
3&-4.36&-5.14&-5.95&-6.79&-7.67\\
4&-7.67&-8.58&-9.51&-10.47&-11.46\\
5&-11.46&-12.47&-13.50&-14.56&-15.64\\
6&-15.64&-16.73&-17.84&-18.98&-20.12\\
7&-20.12&-21.29&-22.47&-23.67&-24.88\\
8&-24.88&-26.11&-27.35&-28.61&-29.87\\
9&-29.87&-31.15&-32.45&-33.75&-35.07\\
10&-35.07&-36.40&-37.74&-39.09&-40.45\\
11&-40.45&-41.82&-43.21&-44.60&-46.00\\
12&-46.00&-47.41&-48.83&-50.26&-51.70\\
13&-51.70&-53.15&-54.61&-56.07&-57.54\\
14&-57.54&-59.02&-60.51&-62.01&-63.51\\
15&-63.51&-65.03&-66.55&-68.07&-69.61\\
16&-69.61&-71.15&-72.69&-74.25&-75.81\\
17&-75.81&-77.38&-78.95&-80.53&-82.12\\
18&-82.12&-83.71&-85.31&-86.92&-88.53\\
19&-88.53&-90.15&-91.77&-93.40&-95.04\\
20&-95.04&-96.68&-98.32&-99.97&-101.63\\
21&-101.63&-103.29&-104.96&-106.63&-108.31\\
22&-108.31&-109.99&-111.68&-113.37&-115.07\\
23&-115.07&-116.77&-118.48&-120.19&-121.91\\
24&-121.91&-123.63&-125.35&-127.08&-128.82\\
\end{array}$$
For $\psi(n,B)/n$ with bounding or/and lower $B$, one can use Bernstein's [psibound](https://cr.yp.to/psibound.html).

Comment: nice, i started drafting an answer but got distracted by other tasks